# How to create a GridView with views inside cells using a spinner

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-custom-view

I want to generate a GridView, the number of columns is always 5 what changes is the number of rows, i have a spinner with numbers from 5 to 10 which dictates how many rows the grid should have.
Besides just genereting the grid i also want for each of the cells to have a view inside them once the grid is created, it's a custom view called EmptyCell.
How do i do that?

This is the function that should create a GridView:

```
private View createGrid(int numRow){

        GridView gridview = findViewById(R.id.grid_table);
        gridview.setNumColumns(5);

        GridAdapter gridadapter = new GridAdapter(WeekEditing.this, numRow);
        gridview.setAdapter(gridadapter);

        return gridview;
    }
```

And this is the custom adapter that i wrote:

```
package com.example.teacherplanner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int numRows;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, int numRows) {
        this.context = context;
        this.numRows = numRows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numRows * 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_cell, parent, false);
        }

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        convertView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My idea was to add a GripView in the XML file and to change it whnever i would call the function but my program keeps crashing

Comment: Is your gridView layout actually inflated before you make a calls like findViewById?

Comment: I made an XML file with a GridView with the id "grid_table"